# Understanding on how exactly Realm OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener works?

Tags: android, realm, listener

I am currently working with Realm 3.0.0 update. I want the functionality to detect all the deletions, insertions and modifications in my existing channels list. So for that I am using OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener listener with my RealmResult as follows:

```
final RealmResults<Channel> persistedChannels = realmRepository.getPersistedChannels();

    persistedChannels.addChangeListener(new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<Channel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Channel> collection, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {
            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] deletions = changeSet.getDeletionRanges();
            for (int i = deletions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range = deletions[i];
                Log.d(TAG, "onDelete() called with: range startIndex = [" + range.startIndex + "]");
                Log.d(TAG, "onDelete() called with: range length = [" + range.length + "]");

                for (int j = range.startIndex; j < (range.startIndex + range.length); j++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChange() called with: collection " +
                            "= [" + collection.get(j).getChannelName() + "]");
                }
            }

            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] insertions = changeSet.getInsertionRanges();
            for (OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range : insertions) {
            }

            OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range[] modifications = changeSet.getChangeRanges();
            for (OrderedCollectionChangeSet.Range range : modifications) {
            }
        }
    });
```

I found the above reference from this [link](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#collection-notifications)

The problem is that I have initially 5 records so persisted channels realm result is providing me start index 5 and length as 0 in insertion range. But when I delete last entry, In deletion the collection size provides me 4 and cause indexoutofbound exception.

I thought that my initial RealmResult is stored somewhere in collection or persistedchannels array, but after deletion both are of size 4 and I am unable to find my deleted entry on which I have to do some operation.

Please can anyone explain what is going on with collection set that returned and OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener here and let me guide to right path?

Thanks

Comment: your deletion should happen on a different thread, for example `realm.executeTransactionAsync()`; or wait for Realm 3.1

Comment: Buddy, waiting for Realm 3.1 is not an option or solution. Btw when is the Realm 3.1 will come? Will it have updates on OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener?

Comment: No Listener will call only after the execution will finish

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: I have read your blog on medium and tried to understand it that way. But the problem with data is still there. So please help me on this.

Comment: oh now I get it. Deleted entries no longer exist in the Realm. If you "need to do some operation on deleted entry", then you'd need to not delete them from the Realm. Also, the ordered collection change listener returns the indices that changed, but when that happens you have an up-to-date results from which those elements have been removed. I think the ordered collection change listener was primarily designed to keep your UI in sync, like [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters/blob/master/adapters/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.java#L44-L69).

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce, That was a great help. It will lead me to the right path. Thanks. Really appreciated

Comment: As mentioned by @EpicPandaForce, this will be fixed by 3.1. The underlying problem is that the UI might process touch events before Realms listeners are fired. Right now the fix would be to use `executeTransactionAsync()`. A more hacky approach is to do a `realm.beginTransaction();realm.cancelTransaction()` right after your first transaction, which will also trigger notifications.

Comment: Ok @ChristianMelchior: I Will currently find the workaround to perform my operation before I delete it from realm.